# Refactoring C# application tool

Tags: c#, serialization, refactoring

I have a question regarding refactoring I did.
I want to check whether after the change the state of the system and objects are the same.
Because of the system type I can't create the same 2 objects at the same time, but one after the other. The objects are big ones.

I thought about serialize them into a file and compare them.

1. Is there another way to do the comparing ?
2. Do I need not to go over all my objects and add attribute [Serializable] ?
3. What will happen to objects that are COM and don't have that attribute ?
4. If an object consists of another objects will it Serializable it to ?

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is go back to the rules of refactoring.

1. Wrap the code to refactor in unit tests BEFORE refactoring
2. Refactor in small steps
3. Test after EVERY small change

Although I have not used it, Orsol's answer ([Object Comparison API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ivo_manolov/archive/2010/07/29/10043968.aspx)) sounds promising (question 1). As for the serialization path, the .NET wrapper should help with the serialized objects, but you can end up whacking the auto generated code, so this is a short term solution. Serializing to file and comparing is a short path option.

I still think taking the time to set up unit tests is a worthwhile exercise, even if you do not plan on refactoring (or extending, changing, etc) the code again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with [Object Comparison API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ivo_manolov/archive/2010/07/29/10043968.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to refactor your code, first have a safety net of tests. Then, attempt refactoring in baby steps.

Sometimes, you know what you want to refactor; however, many a times you dont know what to refactor (although, you might be guessing that something is wrong). In such situations, you may use design smell detection tools such as [Designite](http://www.designite-tools.com).

Comment: Please declare any affiliation you have with this site/service.